# Is it possible to follow the Black Beauty to wherever it's going?

Tags: the-witcher-3

If you choose to free the spirit in the quest Whispering Hillock, it gallops away from the cave it was in. I've tried keeping up with it, but it always runs away from me when I run into some endrega workers. Is it possible to keep up with it, and find out where it's actually going? Or is there no final destination?

Answer (score 8):

Surprisingly, yes, you're able to keep up with and follow Black Beauty, as seen in this video:

You are able to follow Black Beauty after it runs away.

It looks like it just runs to a random bridge and stops there...

Answer (score 1):

Found her chilling out Northwest from the old tree...

[image]

Here's the Map

Not sure if this will be the same for everyone.

[image]